# How to wrap portions of a string in html to customize color

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, replace

Thanks for any time dedicated to this conundrum, in advance.
I am attempting to reprint the html markup of a button inside of a code element. However, I need to split the code elements up into separate spans, to add some color to the output.
Using Regex and HTML character encoding, I am able to correctly wrap all targeted element strings. This is where I hit the wall.
The out of the code is markup, indeed, but I need the wrapping spans to be only that... wrappers of a particular portion of the code string. I was thinking .split() .join(), but really do not want to deal with a huge array of substrings.

```
<span class="chev"><<span>button id=<span class="quote">">"<span>btn<span class="quote">">"<span> class=<span class="quote">">"<span>btn btn-primary tru-btn<span class="quote">">"<span> data-value=<span class="quote">">"<span>btn-primary<span class="quote">">"<span> type=<span class="quote">">"<span>button<span class="quote">">"<span><span class="chev">><span>Button<span class="chev"><<span>/butt
on<span class="chev">><span>
```

```js
generateHTMLBlock = () => {
  let someButton = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML,
    modBtnCode = someButton.replace(/^.\s+|\s+$/gm, ''),
    btnMarkup = modBtnCode.replace(/(.{100})/g, "$1\r");
  encodeElement = (output) => {
    return output.replace(/</g, '&lt;span class=&quot;chev&quot;&gt;&#60;&lt;span&gt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&lt;span class=&quot;chev&quot;&gt;&#62;&lt;span&gt;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&lt;span class=&quot;quote&quot;&gt;&#34;&lt;/span&gt;');
  let code = encodeElement(btnMarkup);
  document.getElementsByTagName('code').appendChild(code);
};
```

```css
.btn-primary:not(disabled):not(.disabled),
.btn-secondary:not(disabled):not(.disabled) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.338rem 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  border-radius: .625rem;
  border-width: .125rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: none;
  user-select: none;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

pre {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
}

code {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.quote {
  color: green;
}

.chev {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
<pre>
  <code></code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Are your including this on the page in question or are you trying to do this on user supplied code? If your code can access the original element, there are better ways to extract the data.

Comment: On the page. I'm all ears. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: If you have access to the element on the page, you can use the DOM functions to extract attributes and child nodes, instead of trying to parse the HTML with regex. For example `getAttributeNames` get you all the attributes of an element.

Comment: @Nick the rendered output should be just the button code:
<button id="btn" class=btn btn-primary">Button</button> ...
But
... I need to wrap certain chars in spans that render as html so I can use css to customize the aesthetics of the redering.

Comment: @some I am open to suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: BAM! -> Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529534/how-to-change-colour-of-specific-characters-jquery-regex. Need to to wrap the opening carets of the button...
`<span class="red><</span><button.../>`
I am attempting to achieve the view of an RTE in an HTML <code> element - Simplest terms

Comment: Look at my answer. Vanilla javascript, no confusion on what is data and what is code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to the element that you want to generate the code for, you can use the DOM methods to extract the data.

This solution doesn't try to parse the HTML with regular expressions, but uses the data parsed by the browser.

By creating a span, and then using `textContent` to set the data, the browser will not treat the code as HTML, but as text.

This is just an example. You have to adopt it for your needs.

```js
function generateHTMLBlock(node) {
  const parent = document.getElementById('output');
  function ce(parent, ...args) {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
      const e = document.createElement('span');
      e.className = args[i + 0];
      e.textContent = args[i + 1];
      parent.appendChild(e);
    }
  }

  function genNode(parent, node) {
    const e = document.createElement('div');
    parent.appendChild(e);
    e.className = 'node';

    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE: {
        e.classList.add('element');
        const tagName = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        ce(e, 'tagStart', '<', 'tagName', tagName);
        for (const attrName of node.getAttributeNames()) {
          ce(
            e,
            'space', ' ',
            'attrName', attrName,
            'attrEqual', '=',
            'attrQuote', '"',
            'attrValue', node.getAttribute(attrName).replace(/"/g, '&quot;'),
            'attrQuote', '"'
          );
        }
        ce(e, 'tagEnd', '>');
        for (const child of node.childNodes) genNode(e, child);
        ce(e, 'tagStart', '</', 'tagName', tagName, 'tagEnd', '>');
        break;
      }
      case Node.TEXT_NODE: {
        e.classList.add('text');
        ce(e, 'textValue', node.textContent.trim());
        break;
      }
      case Node.COMMENT_NODE: {
        e.classList.add('comment');
        ce(e, 'commentStart', '<!--', 'commentValue', node.textContent, 'commentEnd', '-->');
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  genNode(parent, node);
}

generateHTMLBlock(document.getElementById('btn'));
```

```css
body { background-color:#1d1b1b; color:#aaa;}
div.node { white-space: pre-wrap; }
div.node > div.node { margin-left: 2ch; }
div.node.element { }
div.node.text { color:#fff; }
div.node.comment { color:#999; }
.attrQuote, .attrEqual, .tagEnd, .tagStart { color: #fff; }
.tagName { color: #f09449; }
.attrName { color: #88afce; }
.attrValue { color: #bfbd68; }
.attrQuote { color: #bfbd68; }
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="btn-primary" type="button">
    Some text
    <span class="cap">B</span>utton
    <!--A comment <span>Old button</span>-->
  </button>
</div>

<code id="output"></code>
```

Comment: Not sure about your choice of highlighting colours :) but the code is certainly good.

Comment: @Nick Ok, I'll admit they were hideous. I updated them to use similar colors as here on Stackoverflow, when I updated the code.

Comment: Now I feel all warm and fuzzy :)

Comment: I love this place!!! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @some... you are a scholar! Beautiful work! This bit of mastery is slicker than snot on a greased glass door knob. :) With minor mods, this works perfectly. I am humbled, inspired. and enlightened. Many thanks indeed!

Comment: I'm glad you liked it! It won't solve all your problems, but hopefully some :)

Comment: I did a minor tweak: changed the CSS to have margins on `<div>`.  Depending on what you're going to use the code for, you may want to remove the `<div>` to get results inline, and add `<br>` to make line breaks in the appropriate places.